# Commutator subgroup is normal?

Tags: group-theory

Let $P$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $P$, $G$ a normal subgroup of $P$, $[G,H]$ the subgroup of $P$ generated by commutators $[g,h] = ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$, with $g \in G$ and $h \in H$, and $P' = [P,P]$. I know that $[G,H]$ is a subgroup of $P' \cap G$. Is it a normal subgroup? How to prove it? If $H=P$, I know that $[G,H]=[G,P]$ is a normal subgroup of $P' \cap G$. How can I prove it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parts follow from the general result that, for $H,K \le G$, $[H,K]$ is normalized by $H$ and $K$.

This result follows from the commutator identities $[h',k']^h = [h'h,k'][h,k']^{-1}$ and $[h',k']^k = [h',k]^{-1}[h',k'k]$.

(I am using the definitions $[h,k]=h^{-1}k^{-1}hk$ and $h^k=k^{-1}hk$.)

Comment: Can you go further in details please? Or cite some reference? Thanks

Comment: What do you not understand? You can prove the commutator identities by just writing the left and right hand sides of the equations out in full. You can find them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator

Comment: Professor Holt, what do you mean by "$[H,K]$ is normalized by $H$"?

Comment: Now I see, you meant that $[H,K] \triangleleft H$. Ok, thanks for your help

Comment: I mean $H \le N_G([H,K])$. Since $[H,K]$ is not necessarily a subset of $H$,  we cannot always say $[H,K] \lhd H$. But it is always true that $[H,K] \unlhd \langle H,K \rangle$.

Comment: Awesome. Just another doubt. Is this $\langle H,K \rangle = \langle H \cup K \rangle$? The join?

Comment: Yes that's the same thing.